# Printing result of a stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use a stored procedure in T-SQL to print results from a temporary table but I'm having troubles.

Both the 2 examples below would return a "Command(s) completed successfully" message, but not printing / displaying any result.

Proposed solutions in other threads seemed too complicated for me.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

```
--WITH VARIABLE TEMP TABLE

CREATE PROCEDURE spTEST2
    @spSR INT
AS
    DECLARE @SR INT
    DECLARE @SR_REV MONEY
    DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SR_REV MONEY)

    INSERT INTO @T1
        SELECT SUM(OL.SalesAmount) AS SR_REV
        FROM OrderLine AS OL
        WHERE OL.SalesReasonKey = @SR

    SET @SR= @spSR 

    DECLARE @RESULT MONEY

    EXEC @RESULT = spTEST2 1

    SELECT *
    FROM @T1

    PRINT @RESULT

    DROP PROC spTEST2;
GO

--WITH TEMP TABLE
CREATE PROCEDURE spTEST
    @spSR INT
AS
    CREATE TABLE #T1 (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SRKEY INT, SR_REV MONEY)

    INSERT INTO #T1
        SELECT OL.SalesReasonKey AS SRKEY, SUM(OL.SalesAmount) AS SR_REV
        FROM OrderLine AS OL
        GROUP BY OL.SalesReasonKey

    --OL.SalesReasonKey  DATA TYPE: INT
    --OL.SalesAmount DATA TYPE: MONEY

    DECLARE @SR INT  
    DECLARE @SR_REV MONEY

    SET @SR = @spSR 

    SELECT @SR_REV = SR_REV
    FROM #T1
    WHERE #T1.SRKEY = @SR

    DECLARE @SP_RESULT MONEY
    SET @SP_RESULT = @SR_REV

    EXEC @SP_RESULT = spTEST 1

    PRINT @SP_RESULT
    PRINT @SR_REV

    DROP PROC spTEST;
GO
```

After your comments and shared links, I've modified the code, but still doesn't work -this time it doesn't even say "completed successfully":

```
CREATE PROC  spTEST2
@spSR  INT  ,
@spSR_REV MONEY OUTPUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @SR INT
DECLARE @SR_REV MONEY
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SRKEY INT, SR_REV MONEY)

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT OL.SalesReasonKey AS SRKEY, SUM(OL.SalesAmount) AS SR_REV
FROM OrderLine AS OL
GROUP BY OL.SalesReasonKey
HAVING OL.SalesReasonKey = @SR

SET @SR= @spSR 
-------------------------------------------
---VERSION 1
SELECT @SR_REV  = SR_REV
FROM @T1  

SET @SR_REV = @spSR_REV
-------------------------------------------
--VERSION 2 -TRIED AS AN ALTERNATIVE TO VERSION 1
--SELECT @spSR_REV  = SR_REV
--FROM @T1  
-------------------------------------------

RETURN
GO

DECLARE @RESULT MONEY;
EXECUTE spTEST2
1  , @spSR_REV = @RESULT

PRINT @RESULT 
GO
--------------------------------------------
--FOR THE RECORD, THIS WORKS FINE AND PRINTS
CREATE PROCEDURE test3  
@SR INT,  
@SR_rev money OUTPUT  
AS    

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT @SR_rev = SUM( OL.SalesAmount  )
    FROM  OrderLine as OL  
    WHERE OL.SalesReasonKey = @SR;  
RETURN  
GO  

DECLARE @RESULT money;   
EXECUTE test3  
    1, @SR_rev = @RESULT OUTPUT;  

PRINT @RESULT 
GO  
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Remove or comment out the `Drop PROC` statements. See if that works.

Comment: There is no exit condition on your recursion. I don't think the PRINT command is getting hit.

Comment: Best practice  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTEST2
    @spSR INT
AS
    ...
GO


 DECLARE @RESULT MONEY
 EXEC @RESULT = spTEST2 1
 PRINT @RESULT
```

After reading your edited question I think I know what you need to do.   What you need to do is first create all your stored procedures.

```
CREATE spTEST1 GO //In an ideal world you would have already deployed these to you test environment.
CREATE spTEST2 GO 
CREATE spTEST3 GO
```

...Next...

Declare three variables like

```
DECLARE 
    @Result1 MONEY, 
    @Result2 MONEY,
    @Result3 MONEY
```

Then do your calls...

```
EXEC @Result1 = spTEST1 1
EXEC @Result2 = spTEST1 2
EXEC @Result3 = spTEST1 3
```

Or Try this...

```
EXECUTE spTEST1 1, @SR_rev= @Result1 OUTPUT;
EXECUTE spTEST2 2, @SR_rev= @Result2 OUTPUT;
EXECUTE spTEST3 3, @SR_rev= @Result3 OUTPUT;
```

...finally PRINT...

```
PRINT @Result1 
PRINT @Result2 
PRINT @Result3
```

...and that should work.

Comment: Thanks Ross! I've added GO and doesn't work: it prints zero,-which is a step forward- but the result is not zero. This is what I've attempted: